# jQuery check if element is editable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Problem**

I have an editable div containing a few non-editable divs. If a user clicks somewhere I have to find out if he clicked in an area he can actually edit or not.

**Question**

Is there a way to check if an element is editable? Something like this:

```
$('my-element-selector').is(':editable')
```

(And no, the :editable selector is not working, just an example)

Comment: what do you mean by an `editable` div?

Comment: Div with setting contenteditable=true

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#mydiv').get(0).isContentEditable
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.isContentEditable

Comment: Exactly, this works very good. So you need something like that:

     $(".some-div").on("click", function(event) {
     if (event.target.isContentEditable) {
    // this element, where user clicked is contenteditable
    }
    });

Answer (score 3):

As far as i heard, there is no such selector called `:editable` in core jquery, Try to make use of the [`attribute selector`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) at this context,

```
$('my-element-selector').is('[contenteditable="true"]')
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TuM57/)

Comment: Thank you! This unfortunately just checks if the attribute is set on that div, not if the content is *really* editable. If there is a non-editable div containing a few other divs and I have to check if one of these containing divs is editable (which is not) then that one does not have the contenteditable attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$( "div" ).click(function() {
if ( $( this ).hasClass( "editable" ) ) {

}
});
```

OR

```
if ( $( "#myDiv" ).is( ".editable" ) ) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a specific class for editable div and check for class. For example :

```
 if ( $( "#DivId").hasClass( "Editable" ) ) {}
```

Another way :

```
if ( $( "#DivId" ).is( ".Editable" ) ) {

   }
```